# Solr - White space at the end of a keyword return improper results

Tags: solr, full-text-search

When we give white space at the end, Solr gives random results. If we remove the white space at the end, returns exact matching results. Expected result is that we need to get exact match results at both case. (with/without space at the end)

For example:

**No whitespace at the end:**

```
Keyword : “test result”
Result: This is Test Result
```

**Whitespace at the end:**

```
Keyword: “test result  ”
Result: 
This is test result
We have to undergo test
Result will come by tomorrow
```

**Expected result:**

```
Exact match result only should be listed. So in this case only "This is test result" should come
```

To address this issue, we have created a copy field for the field “bodycontent_t” which is used to list the results. And used ‘keyword tokenizer’ analyzer to consider the space at the end.

**Copy field is as follows:**

```
<fieldType name="bodyContent_type" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

<copyField source="bodycontent_t" dest="bodyContentCopied"/>
  <field name="bodyContentCopied" type="bodyContent_type" stored="true" indexed="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

But after the above changes, no results are return.  Please guide me how to handle white space at the end.

Comment: Field with a KeywordTokenizer will only give _exact_ matches. i.e. the content of the field has to be _exactly_ the same. What does your first query look like? What about `Result Test`? i.e. what if both tokens are present, but in the wrong order?

Comment: First query is without space second query is having space at the end. Space at the end caused partial results. Whereas no space at end returns exact match result that's what we are looking for without space case also. We can apply TrimEnd(). But we are looking for a way to control spaces at the end using Solr..

Comment: I understood that from your question, sorry for not being more specific. What is your actual complete _query string_ when making your first query? Are you using `q.op=AND`, what is the field definition, and is the sequence of tokens relevant? (in that case you might be looking for a phrase query)